# Geth node switches to snap sync instead of using full sync

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I'm starting my geth node with `--syncmode=full`, but I immediately get

```
WARN [...] Switch sync mode from full sync to snap sync
```

after starting.

I have previously run a node in snap sync mode on this PC, so that might be causing an issue. I tried clearing the database with `geth removedb`, but that seems to not have helped.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually deleting everything in the data directory seems to have solved the issue.